# Java: duration of movement of Finch Robot

Tags: java, eclipse, robot, finch

I'm new to programming. I have code for my Finch robot that simply loops a zigzag section after the user inputs how many times it should loop for, but how do I input another question that asks how long each zigzag section should be?

For example, the first question I ask is how many zigzag sections the user wants to loop for, but I also want to ask how long each zigzag segment should be (how long each line should be before it turns the other way).

Code:

```java
Finch myFinch = new Finch();
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System. in );

System.out.println("Welcome! Complete the following entries");
System.out.println("Number of zigzag sections:  ");

int noOfTimes = sc.nextInt();

do {
    myFinch.setLED(Color.green);
    myFinch.buzz(600, 2250);
    myFinch.setWheelVelocities(180, 0, 750);
    myFinch.setWheelVelocities(100, 100, 1500);
    myFinch.setLED(Color.red);
    myFinch.buzz(600, 2350);
    myFinch.setWheelVelocities(0, 180, 850);
    myFinch.setWheelVelocities(180, 180, 1500);
    noOfTimes--;

} while ( noOfTimes > 0 );

myFinch.quit();
System.exit(0);
```

Comment: What have you tried? Can you see where the other values are asked for and then scanned in? What happens if you try it yourself? Unfortunately, SO is not a great tutorial site, so you are encouraged to figure this out yourself with the many tutorials you can find online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check java `Scanner` doccumentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

Code sample to accept multiple inputs

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class GetInputFromUser
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
      int a;
      float b;
      String s;

      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.println("Enter an integer");
      a = in.nextInt();
      System.out.println("You entered integer " + a);

      System.out.println("Enter a float");
      b = in.nextFloat();
      System.out.println("You entered float " + b);  

      System.out.println("Enter a string");
      s = in.nextLine();
      System.out.println("You entered string " + s);
   }
}
```